# What determine the language of the Model in a SSAS Tabular solution?

Tags: ssas, tabular, culture

I have 2 tabulars projects, but the language of the model are differents 
(My first one is in English (United State), my second project is in French)
I am confused, i don't know why i have two project with different language, my system, my Visual Studio and even my instances SQL Server are in english. 
First Project : 
[image]
Second Project : 
[image]
I also try to modify the language directly by clicking "View Code" (But he doesn't recognize my modification and he won't let me build the project after the modification).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a solution of this problem as well. In fact you have already been close to it.

1. Open your model in the code view
2. Change the culture to a value appropriate to the default culture, which usually is "en-US"
3. Save and close the solution
4. Open the project folder in Windows Explorer
5. Delete or rename the folders bin and obj
6. Open your solution again
7. Now you are able to Rebuild
8. You have to process the whole database again to get the data

You better change the culture at the very beginning of a new project, then you don't have to delete both folders.
However, it is a shame for an international company like Microsoft that there are still such ugly issues with localization in professional development tools.